# How to use html_safe and convert links to absolute URLs (not relative URLs)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In Rails, how can I render stored HTML and display it with working, absolute links? I have a chunk of HTML that I am calling html_safe on from a view page. When I load the page in the browser, all of the links from that HTML render as relative URLs on my own domain rather than absolute links to the original destination.

**In my console or as a result of a form:**

```
@company.about = "Some info about a <a href="http://google.com">company</a>."
```

**In the view:**

```
<%= @company.about.html_safe %>
```

**What renders in the browser (relative URL):**

Some info about a [company](http://localhost:3000/products/"http://google.com").

**What I would *like* to render in the browser (absolute URL):**

Some info about a [company](http://google.com).

PS - I realize that doing this isn't great practice. But it's not user-submitted content, just my own. And it's a temporary workflow until I decide how to better structure my model to accommodate these links. I'm more surprised that can't find more detailed information on what html_safe actually does w/r/t to links.

Comment: I think this [link](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/String/html_safe) will help you. More detail, don't use `html_safe` to string. If there is something malicious code into your content, you are under the risk of XSS attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this on my rails app, and run (check how i use ' and "):

```
@company.about = 'Some info about a <a href="http://google.com">company</a>.'

<%= @company.about.html_safe %>
```

Comment: This was it! I was entering the HTML into a form with double quotes around the links. Rails was of course wrapping another set of double quotes around that and saving it into @company.about in the database. When it tried to render, it went relative. I've now fixed the HTML inputs in the form as single quotes and Rails is behaving as expected and rendering absolute URLs now. Thanks so much for noticing this error!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with raw?

```
<%= raw @company.about %>
```

or something so (it's not tested, i use this method into prawn, maybe can run:

```
@company.about = "Some info about a #{<a href="http://google.com">company</a>}."
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I hadn't tried using raw but I just did. I'm seeing the exact same issue. The links are still nested into relative URLs rather than displaying as absolute URLs.

Comment: `raw` is equivalent to `html_safe`. Use `sanitize` instead.

Comment: I tried the following without luck -- <%= sanitize @company.about, tags: %w(strong p a), attributes: %w(href) %> Do I need to set anything else up for sanitize?

Answer (score 0):

Personal suggestion. You can save your `about` column as markdown text.

Then use [redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) or something markdown gem to translate model content to html text.

It's safer (redcarpet will deal with it) and more customizable(markdown).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the _url suffix, the generated URL is absolute. Use _path to get a relative URL.

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_url %>

<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

also look at plugin: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/10/actionmailer-and-host-value/